# Passing the most recent file in a directory to a program

Tags: bash, unix, vim, ls, unix-head

What would be the correct way to do the following:

```
$ ls -t | head -n1 | vim -
```

Currently, this will read the 'filename' into vim, but I'm looking at actual open that filename that's passed to it as a string. How would this be done?

Without opening the file we get:

```
$ ls -t | head -n1
2020-11-05.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it like this:

```
$ vim "$(ls -t | head -n1)"
```